# How to show FCM notification only when user closes the app in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Let's say you've triggered FCM notification when the app is in the foreground. Instead of showing the notification in the foreground, Can I schedule the notification when the user closes the app? Is it possible to do it?

Comment: You want to receive notifications when app is in background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the lifecycle extensions to detect when your applications go into the background.

1. Add this to your module `build.gradle` file

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
   }
   ```
2. In your Application class,

   ```
   class MyApplication : Application(), LifecycleObserver {

      override fun onCreate() {
          super.onCreate()
          ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
      }

      @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
      fun onAppBackgrounded() {
         Log.d("MyApp", "Application sent to background")
         // you can save a value here and check it later 
      }

      @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
      fun onAppForegrounded() {
         Log.d("MyApp", "App brought to foreground")
         // don't forget to change the value stored in onAppBackgrounded to detect the app is again in foreground 
      }
   }
   ```
3. Now in your FirebaseMessagingService class, in `onMessageReceived` you can use the value stored previously to check if the application is in the background or not

Comment: Thanks @basil ...this is what I was looking for

Comment: most welcome @topsecret , could you market as the right answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The fcm data being sent should look like this

```
{
"to" : “/topics/global“,

"notification" : {
   "body" : "Some body",
   "title" : "Some title",
 },
"data" : {
   “body" : “Some body“,
   “title" : “Some title“,
   “key" : “value"
   }
}
```

Use remoteMessage.getData() instead of remoteMessage.getNotification(), the notification will be shown when received whether the app is in foreground or background.

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
     sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData());
}

public void sendNotification(HashMap<String, String> data){
     String title = data.get("title");
     String message = data.get("message");  
}
```